# How to close browser after puppeteer exposeFunction

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get data processed by page back to Node.js, but I cannot close browser properly without some non-standard tricks like timeout or attaching event like this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
const page = await browser.pages();
await page[0].goto('file:///...');
page[0].exposeFunction('reader', (html) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, pdf.replace('.pdf', '.htm')), html);
    session.on('Page.lifecycleEvent', event => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        if (event.name === 'firstMeaningfulPaint') browser.close();
    });
});
```

console.log prints something like this

```
{"frameId":"...","loaderId":"...","name":"networkAlmostIdle","timestamp":332671.943465}
{"frameId":"...","loaderId":"...","name":"firstMeaningfulPaint","timestamp":332673.046969}
```

In case close is next to writeFileSync, Node.js throw this exception (reader function result is sent back to closed browser).

```
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Target closed.
    at puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:183:56
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:182:12)
    at Page._onBindingCalled (puppeteer\lib\Page.js:568:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {message: 'Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Target closed.', stack: 'Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Tar…ctions (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)'}
```

(there were aprox. 28 session events available)

```
session.on('Fetch.requestPaused', event => { console.log('Fetch.requestPaused'); });
session.on('Fetch.authRequired', event => { console.log('Fetch.authRequired'); });
session.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', event => { console.log('Network.requestWillBeSent'); });
session.on('Network.requestServedFromCache', event => { console.log('Network.requestServedFromCache'); });
session.on('Network.responseReceived', event => { console.log('Network.responseReceived'); });
session.on('Network.loadingFinished', event => { console.log('Network.loadingFinished'); });
session.on('Network.loadingFailed', event => { console.log('Network.loadingFailed'); });
session.on('Page.frameAttached', event => { console.log('Page.frameAttached'); });
session.on('Page.frameNavigated', event => { console.log('Page.frameNavigated'); });
session.on('Page.navigatedWithinDocument', event => { console.log('Page.navigatedWithinDocument'); });
session.on('Page.frameDetached', event => { console.log('Page.frameDetached'); });
session.on('Page.frameStoppedLoading', event => { console.log('Page.frameStoppedLoading'); });
session.on('Runtime.executionContextCreated', event => { console.log('Runtime.executionContextCreated'); });
session.on('Runtime.executionContextDestroyed', event => { console.log('Runtime.executionContextDestroyed'); });
session.on('Runtime.executionContextsCleared', event => { console.log('Runtime.executionContextsCleared'); });
session.on('Page.lifecycleEvent', event => { console.log('Page.lifecycleEvent'); });
session.on('Target.attachedToTarget', event => { console.log('Target.attachedToTarget'); });
session.on('Target.detachedFromTarget', event => { console.log('Target.detachedFromTarget'); });
session.on('Page.domContentEventFired', event => { console.log('Page.domContentEventFired'); });
session.on('Page.loadEventFired', event => { console.log('Page.loadEventFired'); });
session.on('Runtime.consoleAPICalled', event => { console.log('Runtime.consoleAPICalled'); });
session.on('Runtime.bindingCalled', event => { console.log('Runtime.bindingCalled'); });
session.on('Page.javascriptDialogOpening', event => { console.log('Page.javascriptDialogOpening'); });
session.on('Runtime.exceptionThrown', event => { console.log('Runtime.exceptionThrown'); });
session.on('Inspector.targetCrashed', event => { console.log('Inspector.targetCrashed'); });
session.on('Performance.metrics', event => { console.log('Performance.metrics'); });
session.on('Log.entryAdded', event => { console.log('Log.entryAdded'); });
session.on('Page.fileChooserOpened', event => { console.log('Page.fileChooserOpened'); });
```

Comment: so correct me if im wrong but u have ur solution already and u want a more elegant one??

Comment: i mean.. i assumed u tried using fresh async block inside the exposefunction, then await browser.close and that jazz, if that didn't work, well yea go unconventional

Comment: Quite strange problem - even not visible without debugger. Timeout is bad as it is random also this one works, but is ugly, maybe I shoud try some github issue. And funny is you cannot close window inside page too ;-) (or isn't it because I am reusing existing tab?)